# Eliminar campos vacios en array PHP

Tags: php, firebird

Con php y html estoy haciendo una página que contiene un formulario, a través del cual se hace consultas a una base de datos en Firebird.

*Tengo dos modelos:*

- **El primero**, funciona correctamente, ya que sólo hace consultas de búsqueda y actualización de UN SÓLO registro cada vez:

  ```
  //Por un lado tengo el formulario en html (pongo sólo el botón y la cabecera):

  form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="post"

  input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Actualizar" 

  //Y por otro lado (en la misma página) tengo el .php

  if (isset($_POST["btn1"])){
   $btn=$_POST["btn1"];

      if ($btn=="Actualizar"){
      $sqlStr= ' ';

       //Saco un nuevo array con los campos vacíos del formulario eliminados.
        if (!empty($POST_){
        unset ($_POST['btn1']);
        for each ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                     if (trim($value) != '') {
                       $sqlArr[]="$key='$value'";
  }}}

       //convierto array a string
      $sqlStr=implode(", ", $sqlArr);

     $sql = "update tabla set $sqlStr";
  ```

En definitiva, haciendo esto actualizo el registro sin problemas, ya que aunque los campos estén vacios, el string último se me queda tal y como quiero (ID='1', NOMBRE='2'...).

- **El segundo** método es para hacer una búsqueda y que imprima más de un registro. Cada fila resultante tendrá al lado un botón "actualizar", el cual va a hacer un update de esa fila. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

**listar.php:**

```
//en php:

if (isset($_POST["btn1"])){
     $btn=$_POST["btn1"];

        if ($btn=="Buscar"){

   $sql="consulta sql"

<form name='ejecuta' action='ejecuta2.php' method='post'>

<tr>
<td>ID_AGENTE</td>
<td>ID_COLABORADOR</td>
<td>ID_PERSONA</td>
</tr>

$i=0;

    while ($resul=ibase_fetch_row($cs)){
   $var=$resul[0];
   $var1='resul[1];
   $var2=$resul[2];

echo "<tr>
<td>
<input name='ID_AGENTE[$i]' value='".$var."' /></td>
<input name='ID_ COLABORADOR[$i]' value='".$var1."' /></td>
<input name='ID_PERSONA[$i]' value='".$var2."' /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name='seleccion[$i]' value='Actualizar'></td>
</tr>";
$i++;
}
echo "</table></form>;
```

Esto me funciona relativamente bien, ya que muestra bien el formulario y a la hora de hacer la búsqueda me muestra por pantalla todos los registros.

El problema viene al usar el submit con el nombre *seleccion[$i]* y *value Actualizar*.

He intentado basarme en el codigo php del primer modelo, haciendo esto:

**ejecuta2.php:**

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST['seleccion'] as $indice => $valor){
//verificamos que se ha dado al boton actualizar.
$opcion=substr ($_POST['seleccion'][$indice],0,-1); //extraemos la parte de la cadena que será "Actualizar".

switch ($opcion) {

     case: "Actualizar":

          if (!empty($_POST)){

               if (trim($valor) != ''){
              $sqlArr[]="$indice='$valor'";}}

print_r $sqlArr;

     sql="$sql = "update tabla set $sqlStr";
    break;

?>
```

Seguramente haya algo mal al pasar mi código a este, pero en conclusión, lo que no sé es de qué forma eliminar campos vacíos en el array según el formulario que tengo en el segundo modelo para que al final tenga un string del tipo: ID='1', NOMBRE='JOSE'.

He intentado ponerlo de varias formas y siempre siempre siempre, al hacer el procedimiento de borrado con el array, siempre obtengo: 0='Actualizar'.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer script das forma a la sentencia de update haciendo

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if (trim($value) != '') {
      $sqlArr[]="$key='$value'";
   }
}
```

Que es una forma bastante artesanal de armar una consulta SQL, y **muy propensa a las inyecciones SQL**, pero no me quiero extender sobre ese tema porque está fuera del alcance de la pregunta.

En tu último script estás poniendo

```
foreach ($_POST['seleccion'] as $indice => $valor){
    ....
    if (!empty($_POST)){
       if (trim($valor) != ''){ // <-- pero si ya sabes que $valor es "Actualizar"
         $sqlArr[]="$indice='$valor'";
       }
    }
    ....
}
```

Resulta que `$_POST['seleccion']` es un array numérico que contiene uno o más valores `'Actualizar'` y sólo con eso estás intentando armar tu sentencia de update.

Creo que, por un lado, tienes que modificar el segundo script para recorrer el contenido de `$_POST` en vez de `$_POST['seleccion']` y, por otro lado, armar tu HTML de otra manera, porque en este momento tienes un solo formulario para N submits, pero todos ellos hacen lo mismo, enviar la tabla completa.

Comment: Antes de nada, te agradezco enormemente tu ayuda @amenadiel.

Me he basado en lo que dices pero sigue sin funcionar.

Cuando pulso Actualizar en una fila, mi print_r($_POST) me tira esto:

Array ( [ID_AGENTE] => 2508 [ID_COLABORADOR] =>  [ID_PERSONA] => 1 [seleccion] => Actualizar )

Lo que quiero es que me recoja el array correspondiente a la fila donde esté el botón actualizar y que si id_colaborador está vacío (como en este array), directamente me recoja:

Array ( [ID_AGENTE] => 2508  [ID_PERSONA] => 1 [seleccion] => Actualizar ).

La verdad es que estoy bastante estancado:/

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien que quieres hacer con tus inputs vacios supongo los quieres llenar, pues verifica que con

```
   if($variable[POST]empty){ 
       $variable[POST].setValue("tuValorpordefecto"); 
   }

//para eliminarlos podrias hacer algo así, el trim que ocupas lo que hace es verificar tu cadena y purificarla del caracter que le pongas en los parametros de la funcion.
```

Lo siguiente que veo: no soy experto pero siento que tu $i en tu segundo método está fijando todos los valores a 0 de tu filas, toma tu ID de los campos ['ID'] de la base de datos, pasalo por POST. debería actualizar el valor en tu fichero el cual debe estar programado con GET.

tu $i es la que te setea a 0 y creo que por eso no actualiza. checalo.